# Multilingual attribute routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I use different languages for attribute route in ASP.NET Core/MVC?

For example, I have a User Controller that can edit user information:

```
[Route("user")]
public class UserController : Controller {
    [HttpGet("edit/{id}/{username}")]
    public IActionResult Edit (int id) {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

What can I do to support more languages? I want the server to generate links that depend on the language the user is choosing:

```
@{ var user = ...; }
<a asp-controller="User"
   asp-action="Edit"
   asp-route-id="@user.Id"
   asp-route-username="@user.Username">
    Edit
</a>

// The code above will generate
English link => <a href="/user/edit/1/smith">Edit</a>
Spanish link => <a href="/usuario/editar/1/smith">Editar</a>
etc...
```

Comment: Use resources files.

Comment: It's a bad idea to change the language of the URL segments, spanish _might_ quite work, but with other languages, you'd run into heavy difficulties with the encoding (imagine chinese...). Instead, it's best practice to use a culture indicator as the first path element, e.g. `/es-es/user/edit/1/smith`. That said, there are some tutorials around how to accomplish localized routes (e.g. https://www.strathweb.com/2015/11/localized-routes-with-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6/)